# How to add a value to an inputText in tcomb-form-native?

Tags: forms, react-native, tcomb-form-native, tcomb

I'am new in react native , and i'am using tcomb-form library to create forms for my app.
I want to add a default values to some of my fields, means when they first appear they must have values by default.
This is what i tried so far but the field still appears empty :

```
this.Position = t.struct({
      PosName: FormFields.String,
    });
fields:{
PosName: {
          placeholder: "Name der Position",
          error: "Dieses Feld ist erforderlich",
          label: "Name der Position",
          value: "some text here ",
          template: Template
        },
//... other fields here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an object with your fields and your default values and then pass it to your form element like this:

```
// your object definition
    let value = {
         PostName: 'some text here',
         {... other fields}
    }
```

And then on your render:

```
<Form type={this.Position} value={value}
```

Here's the docs: [tcomb-form-native default values](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native#default-values)

Comment: thanks for your response !
This works for me only with the initial values of my object , i mean when the state changes the form component does not display the new values of the object.
P.S : i changed <Form type={this.Position} value={value}
by <Form type={this.Position} value={this.state.value}